# When mousing over any control in this user control, the text of every label turns red

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom user control that contains `asp:ValidationSummary`. It is placed on a page along with other controls that display data. When I try to save the page and the validation fires, I get the following, strange behavior:

If I mouse over any controls on the page, all labels turn to red color.  When the cursor leaves page, they return to the color specified in their CSS. I did not find any code for mouseover, etc...

I wonder if the ValidationSummary is doing something that I am not aware of? I appreciate any feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: could you show us your client side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test this theory, change the color of the validation summary to blue and try it again. If your controls turn blue, then yes I would say it's your validation summary.

Since the validation summary is client side, I wouldn't recommend putting it in a custom control unless you have a very explicit reason to.